# onTabChanged(first_page) is always called, is this expected behavior?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have TabActivity with 3 tabs. I save last selected page number to shared
preference and get it back onResume to call `tabHost.setCurrentTab()`.
But `onTabChanged()` is called twice when selecting other than first
page.

- Calling `tabHost.setCurrentTab(0)` makes `onTabChanged` called once. This is expected.
- Calling `tabHost.setCurrentTab(1 or above)` makes `onTabChanged` called twice, specifying first page and the expected page. This is not what I expected.

I'm running it on OS2.3.3.

Is this expected (designed) behavior? (I prefer `onTabChanged` will be called only once to
prevent unwanted processing for first page. If this is designed behavior I need to think
some logic to ignore unwanted call to `onTabChanged.`)

**EDIT**

Code fragment in onCreate().

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabChangedListener());
TabSpec firstTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("First")
    .setIndicator(firstButton)
    .setContent(R.id.first_content);
tabHost.addTab(firstTab);
TabSpec secondTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second")
    .setIndicator(secondButton)
    .setContent(R.id.second_content);
tabHost.addTab(secondTab);
TabSpec thirdTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third")
    .setIndicator(thirdButton)
    .setContent(R.id.third_content);
tabHost.addTab(thirdTab);
```

And code in onResume().

```
int tabIndex = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(ADDRESS_TAB_KEY,0);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabIndex);
```

And OnTabChangeListener.

```
class TabChangedListener implements OnTabChangeListener
{
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"onTabChanged " + tabId);

        if(tabId.equals("First") == true)
        {
            setupView(0);
        }
        else if(tabId.equals("Second") == true)
        {
            setupView(1);
        }
        else if(tabId.equals("Third") == true)
        {
            setupView(2);
        }
    }
}
```

I found that onTabChanged() is called before onResume() is called! When I moved a line calling tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener() after calling tabHost.addTab(), onTabChanged() was not called from onCreate() which seems understandable. But, in this case, calling tabHost.setCurrentTab(0) won't call onTabChanged at all! This is ridiculous. So I ended up with this solution.

1) Call tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener after calling tabHost.addTab().
2) Twisted onResume() code as shown below.

```
int tabIndex = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(ADDRESS_TAB_KEY,0);
if(tabIndex == 0)
{
    setupView(0);   // setup view since onTabChanged won't be called
}
else
{
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabIndex);
}
```

Now I have my solution and questions are:

- Is this an expected behavior?
- Is there any better solution for this?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Mind sharing the `onCreate` and `onResume` methods only tab relevant code?

Comment: @Nikola, Yes I added code fragment.

Comment: Did you fix it already? or still need help?

Comment: @Jeroen, as you can see in my question, I have my own solution but no answer to my questions. Since I'm still working on Android app, I'm happy to know answers.

Comment: I had similar issue, found a solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9896017/2596190

This might help

Answer (score 0):

We have no code so it's kinda hard to tell the exact reason but you most probably are calling setCurrentTab from you onCreate too. When you get back to the activity you call first the setCurrentTab in the onCreate method, and after that the setCurrentTab in the onResume method gets called.

If that's not the problem you gonna have to share some code to lets a help.

Actually, you should always share relevant portions of code or it gets really difficult to find the real problems.

Comment: I investigated more. If I call tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener before I call tabHost.addTab, onTabChanged is called. And I call ONE tabHost.setCurrentTab which calls onTabChanged again if index is not 0. I try to edit my question to add code fragment.